# salesforce mobile sdk access to UserInfo class

Tags: android, rest, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I have created a mobile app in Android and iOS using the Salesforce SDK.
I want to add functionality of multi currency by using isMultiCurrencyOrganization() method from the UserInfo class.
Now I am quite new to Salesforce mobile SDK so I don't know how I can use the methods of UserInfo class and check if user's organization has multi-currency enabled.